# Castle Windsor equivalent of StructureMap ObjectFactory.With<>().GetInstance<>()

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

With StructureMap one can do a resolution and force the container to use specific dependency instance provided at the time of resolution like so:

```
ObjectFactory.With<ISomeDependency>(someDepedencyInstance).GetInstance<IServiceType>()
```

Provided instance will be used in whole resolution chain, that is not only as a direct dependency of IServiceType implementation but also as a dependency of any direct and indirect dependencies of IServiceType implementation.

**How do I do something like that in Castle Windsor?**

I know I can provide a direct dependency with an overload of IWindsorContainer.Resolve<>(), but I need to provide this dependency to something deeper.

Comment: Could you further explain what you're trying to achieve? it's not quite clear

Comment: Normally overrides are done at registration time, not at resolution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an instance as the implementation of a given component like this:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<ISomeDependency>()
    .Instance(someDependencyInstance));
```

This means that everytime you resolve *anything* and ISomeDependency is part of the resolved object graph, the `someDependencyInstance` instance will be used.

It that what you want, or did I misunderstand the question?

---

Based on additional information, here's a new attempt at answering the question.

You should be able to use container hierarchies for this. If a Windsor container can't resolve a type, it'll ask its parent. This means that you can create a child container that contains only the override and then ask that container to resolve the type for you.

Here's an example:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component
    .For<ISomeDependency>()
    .ImplementedBy<SomeDependency>());
container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<Service>());

var childContainer = new WindsorContainer();
childContainer.Register(Component
    .For<ISomeDependency>()
    .ImplementedBy<SomeOtherDependency>());

childContainer.Parent = container;

var service = childContainer.Resolve<IService>();
```

The resolved `service` will contain an instance of SomeOtherDependency and not SomeDependency.

Notice how `childContainer` only overrides the registration of ISomeDependency. All other registrations are used from the parent.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but my need is different. Let's say I have ISomeDependency registered in the container, but for some specific, single resolution I want to force a specific instance (different than the registered one) that I provide at the time of resolution.

Comment: Yes, thank you Mark, that would be it. Although I must say that StructureMap makes this particular scenario way easier. Also, how do I get rid of the child container (make it available for GC)? Do I just let it go off the scope or should I set Parent to null, or maybe call container.RemoveChildContainer(childContainer)?

Comment: WindsorContainer implements IDisposable, so the correct thing would be to call its Dispose method, but first remove it from the parent by calling RemoveChildContainer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named component and service overrides:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeDependency>()
    .ImplementedBy<SomeDependency>());
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeDependency>()
    .ImplementedBy<SomeOtherDependency>()
    .Named("other"));
container.Register(Component.For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<Service>()
    .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("dep").Eq("other")));
```

See [this article](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,6c1a25f7-5c8c-4a5e-bda9-04ffa944ebd0.aspx) for more information on service overrides.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP is asking about. This will use "other" for all created instances of IService. I thought the question was whether you could override the behavior for a particular invocation of Resolve, but I might be wrong...

Comment: The point is to override the behaviour for a particular invocation of Resolve.

Comment: Normally overrides are done at registration time, not at resolution time.