# Is WindsorContainers AddChildContainer really this bad?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm am trying to branch a number of child containers from a basic set of registrations in order to facilitate different configuration settings.

I thought based on [Mark Seemanns reply on how child containers work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974224/castle-windsor-equivalent-of-structuremap-objectfactory-with-getinstance) that I could use child containers to override specific components in a base registration. However I does not seem to work as Seemann claims.

According to Mark this should work:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void OverrideRegistrationInParentContainer()
{
    //IBusinessComponent depends on IBasicComponent
    var parentContainer = new WindsorContainer();
    parentContainer.Register(Component.For<IBasicComponent>().ImplementedBy<BasicComponent>()); //Returns 42
    parentContainer.Register(Component.For<IBusinessComponent>().ImplementedBy<RealBusinessComponent>()); //Returns the result of IBasicComponent


    var childContainer = new WindsorContainer();
    childContainer.Register(Component.For<IBasicComponent>().ImplementedBy<BasicComponent2>()); //Returns 40

    parentContainer.AddChildContainer(childContainer);

    var service = childContainer.Resolve<IBusinessComponent>();
    Assert.AreEqual(40, service.GetBusinessValue()); //This fails with the actual value being 42
}
```

However all dependencies are apparently resolved from the parent.

If i remove the IBasicComponent registration from the parentContainer, I am not even able to resolve the dependency due to missing registrations.

Can anyone explain how you get the container to behave as Seemann claims, or is the WindsorContainer really unable to handle this type of configuration in a graceful manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're referring to used to work in old Windsor versions but was altered in more recent versions.

Basically this is a bug, and it would allow components from child container to be visible outside its scope (when a component form parent takes a dependency on a component from child)

So the dependencies are allowed to go from child --> parent but not the other way around.

Comment: I saw your blog-post on the subject, and from what I could conclude from my tests, Windsor is indeed behaving as you say... I just needed to make sure, that I hadn't missed anything. :-( I really hope that this bug will be removed soon. But thanks for the quick reply

Comment: To be clear, to bug was the old behavior that Mark was explaining. What you're observing is, semantically, more correct.

Comment: Semantically I agree, Marks example is very ugly. But what would be nice, was if i could ommit some registrations in the parent (i.e. components to external ressources) and let the child-containers specify those missing dependencies. Then one child could be production with live components, another child for integration test with stubs etc. (I am aware that som brain thrust would be needed to solve the issue of singletons in the parent container gracefully)

Comment: So, given the new behavior how could you configure the child container to inject BasicComponent2 into RealBusinessComponent when childContainer.Relolve<IBusinessComponent>() is called?