# WindsorCastle child container resolving parent dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ioc-container

My task is to inject specific non-direct child dependency if a top level dependency is of some type. I've tried achieving this with subcontainers, but it does not work as I expected.

I have a next class hierarchy:

```
PRMController: ApiController
    -> PManager: IManager
        -> Repository: IRepository
            -> RepositoryConnection: IRepositoryConnection
                   RepositoryConnection() { /*use default config name*/ }
                   RepositoryConnection(string configName)
```

The windsor container has next registrations:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
            Pick()
            .Configure(c =>
            {
                c.Named(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                c.IsFallback();
            })
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient()
            );

var childContainer = new WindsorContainer()
        .Register(
            Component.For<IRepositoryConnection>().ImplementedBy<RepositoryConnection>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("configName", "PRM"))
                .LifestyleTransient()
            );
        container.AddChildContainer(childContainer);
```

Now for PRM controller it should use the "PRM" configName. And therefore the child container is used to resolve the PRM controller. But the `RepositoryConnection` is resolved with a default config.

```
childContainer.Resolve<IRepositoryConnection>(); //as expected, resolves from child container registrations
childContainer.Resolve<PRMController>(); //NOT as expected, the underlying repositoryConnection is from parent container
```

Can someone please shed a light on that?
I thought windsor would prefer child container dependencies if they exist even if resolving from within child container for a type registered in a parent container.
If that is not achievable, I would be grateful if someone could lead me in the right direction.

**Update:**
According to to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004066/is-windsorcontainers-addchildcontainer-really-this-bad) there is a bug. So is it going to be resolved? What other strategy for the described scenario could I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have achieved what I wanted through the IHandleSelector, so in `HasOpinion` do a check for the service and whether current Url is for `PRMController`. `SelectHandler` returns the required type of `IRepositoryConnection`.

I would better stick with the child container, as at the controller factory I know exactly which controller it is, while with handle selector I need to parse it from Request.Url.

Unfortunately the child container route seems to be not behaving as expected (at least as I expected) in Windsor 3.2 and 3.3.